# Primefaces selectOneRadio ajax

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectoneradio

I'm trying to display validation messages everytime the user clicks on a radio button.

This only works when I click on the submit button, but not when I click on the radio button:

```
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:panel id="panel">
            <ui:repeat value="#{questionsBean}" var="question">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
                    <h:outputText value="#{question.questionText}" />
                    <p:selectOneRadio id="question" value="#{question.response}"
                        validator="#{question.validate}" required="true">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="No" />
                        <p:ajax update="msgQuestion" event="change"/>
                    </p:selectOneRadio>
                    <p:message for="question" id="msgQuestion" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </ui:repeat>
            <p:commandButton id="btn" value="Save" update="panel" partialSubmit="true"/>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: This appears to be related to the ui:repeat...works fine without ui:repeat on a single question.

Comment: Please refer to this:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551145/selectoneradio-inside-subtable-ajax-call-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The HTML DOM `change` event is the wrong event when you want to listen on whether the radio button (or checkbox) is clicked. You should be using the `click` event for this.

The value of the radio button (and checkbox) basically never changes. It has always the same value. The question is more whether that value will be sent to the server side or not. This is determined by the "checked" state which is usually triggered by the DOM `click` event.

The actual behaviour of the `change` event on radiobuttons/checkboxes is dependent on the webbrowser used. The behaviour is particulary inconsistent in the IE browser. It not only depends on the version used, but also in the rendering mode used (quirks mode vs standards mode). Perhaps you were actually using IE while testing.

The default `event` type of the PrimeFaces `<p:ajax>` (and the standard JSF `<f:ajax>`), which is `valueChange` already automatically covers this:

```
<p:ajax update="msgQuestion" event="valueChange" />
```

This will autogenerate the right `change` event handler in text inputs and dropdowns and the `click` event handler in radiobuttons and checkboxes.

But as said, it's the *default* `event` type already. Just omit it altogether.

```
<p:ajax update="msgQuestion" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. If I remove the ui:repeat it works fine.