# SelectOneRadio inside subtable ajax call not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 3.4.1 and I'm trying to use a SelectOneRadio with an ajax call inside a [subtable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableSubTable.jsf)
but it doesn't work, the ajax listener isn't called

```
<p:dataTable id="competenciesTable" var="competency" value="#{evaluationControl.currentEvaluation.evaluatedCompetencies}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{gchmsg['global.competencies']}" />
                </f:facet>
                <p:subTable id="descriptorsTable" var="descriptor" value="#{competency.evaluationDescriptors}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText class="strong" value="#{competency.competency.name}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:column>#{descriptor.descriptor.description}</p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:selectOneRadio required="true" styleClass="calification_scale" id="descriptorCalification" value="#{descriptor.calification}" converter="calification">  
                            <f:selectItems value="#{competency.competency.calificationSchema.scales}" var="scale" itemLabel="#{scale.qualitativeValue}" itemDescription="#{scale.description}" itemValue="#{scale}" />
                            <p:ajax process="@this" listener="#{evaluationControl.handleRadioChange}" update=":evaluationForm:finalResultText, descriptorCalificationMsg" />
                        </p:selectOneRadio> 
                        <p:message id="descriptorCalificationMsg" for="descriptorCalification" display="icon" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:subTable>
            </p:dataTable>
```

The evaluationControl is a SessionBean and the method is

```
public void handleRadioChange() {
    log.debug("Listener called");
}
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the scope of your bean `evaluationControl`?

Comment: @elias It's SessionScoped

Comment: Is it your `p:dataTable` inside a form?

Comment: Check you don't have any javascript error when this page is charged, with a web development tool like *firebug* or similar. Check that `:evaluationForm:finalResultText` and `descriptorCalificationMsg` are really taking this id's in the generated html. Otherwise, JSF will break.

Answer (score 6):

After too many debugging and tests I finally found the issue, the primefaces Subtable component doesn't put back the values to the Backing Bean for itself you must process the whole DataTable component, so I had to remove the `required="true"`(to avoid validation errors) for each selectOneRadio and add the `process="competenciesTable"` to the `p:ajax`

Answer (score 0):

You can try, deleting process="@this". It worked in my case. I'm not sure why it happens with p:subTable because I've never had this issue with p:dataTable.